# Select from_Json DF casting results null

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following DF on Databricks

```
locations
{"accuracy": 1714, "activity": null, "altitude": null, "deviceTag": 1968164841, "heading": null, "latitudeE7": -229307984, "locationMetadata": null, "longitudeE7": -470457350, "platform": null, "platformType": null, "source": "CELL", "timestampMs": "1387043008129", "velocity": null, "verticalAccuracy": null}
{"accuracy": 1714, "activity": null, "altitude": null, "deviceTag": 1968164841, "heading": null, "latitudeE7": -229307984, "locationMetadata": null, "longitudeE7": -470457350, "platform": null, "platformType": null, "source": "CELL", "timestampMs": "1387043018029", "velocity": null, "verticalAccuracy": null}
{"accuracy": 1714, "activity": [{"activity": [{"confidence": 55, "type": "STILL"}, {"confidence": 36, "type": "UNKNOWN"}, {"confidence": 7, "type": "IN_VEHICLE"}], "timestampMs": "1387043032201"}], "altitude": null, "deviceTag": 1968164841, "heading": null, "latitudeE7": -229307984, "locationMetadata": null, "longitudeE7": -470457350, "platform": null, "platformType": null, "source": "CELL", "timestampMs": "1387043023050", "velocity": null, "verticalAccuracy": null}
{"accuracy": 1714, "activity": [{"activity": [{"confidence": 100, "type": "TILTING"}], "timestampMs": "1387043078399"}], "altitude": null, "deviceTag": 1968164841, "heading": null, "latitudeE7": -229307984, "locationMetadata": null, "longitudeE7": -470457350, "platform": null, "platformType": null, "source": "CELL", "timestampMs": "1387043068852", "velocity": null, "verticalAccuracy": null}
```

I convert it into a temp table using `DF.createOrReplaceTempView('events')` . I need to get the values of the json so I can do a subselect and transform into a table view, but the results are all null. I´m using the following SQL... can someone help me see what I´m missing??

```
select from_json(CAST(locations AS STRING),
"accuracy LONG,
activity struct<
    activity: struct<
        confidence: LONG, 
        type: STRING>, 
    timestampMS: STRING>,
altitude LONG, 
deviceTag LONG, 
heading LONG, 
latitudeE7 LONG, 
locationMetadata struct<
    timestampMS: STRING, 
    wifiScan: struct<
        accessPoints: struct<
            mac: LONG, 
            strenght: LONG>>>, 
longitudeE7 LONG, 
plataform STRING, 
plataformType STRING, 
source STRING, 
timestampMS STRING, 
velocity LONG, 
verticalAccuracy LONG") e
from events
```

Here is the result

```
events
{"accuracy": null, "activity": null, "altitude": null, "deviceTag": null, "heading": null, "latitudeE7": null, "locationMetadata": null, "longitudeE7": null, "plataform": null, "plataformType": null, "source": null, "timestampMS": null, "velocity": null, "verticalAccuracy": null}
{"accuracy": null, "activity": null, "altitude": null, "deviceTag": null, "heading": null, "latitudeE7": null, "locationMetadata": null, "longitudeE7": null, "plataform": null, "plataformType": null, "source": null, "timestampMS": null, "velocity": null, "verticalAccuracy": null}
{"accuracy": null, "activity": null, "altitude": null, "deviceTag": null, "heading": null, "latitudeE7": null, "locationMetadata": null, "longitudeE7": null, "plataform": null, "plataformType": null, "source": null, "timestampMS": null, "velocity": null, "verticalAccuracy": null}
{"accuracy": null, "activity": null, "altitude": null, "deviceTag": null, "heading": null, "latitudeE7": null, "locationMetadata": null, "longitudeE7": null, "plataform": null, "plataformType": null, "source": null, "timestampMS": null, "velocity": null, "verticalAccuracy": null}
```

Here the types of the json DF

```
locations:struct
accuracy:long
activity:array
    element:struct
        activity:array
            element:struct
                confidence:long
                type:string
                timestampMs:string
altitude:long
deviceTag:long
heading:long
latitudeE7:long
locationMetadata:array
    element:struct
        timestampMs:string
        wifiScan:struct
            accessPoints:array
                element:struct
                    mac:string
                    strength:long
longitudeE7:long
platform:string
platformType:string
source:string
timestampMs:string
velocity:long
verticalAccuracy:long
```

Comment: I solutioned in a diferent way. Since I´m using Databricks I wrote the solution in PySpark instead using SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I solutioned in a diferent way. Since I´m using Databricks I wrote the solution in PySpark instead using SQL . 

   DF1 = DF.select(
  'locations.accuracy', 
  'locations.activity', 
  'locations.altitude', 
  'locations.deviceTag', 
  'locations.heading', 
  'locations.latitudeE7', 
  'locations.locationMetadata', 
  'locations.longitudeE7', 
  'locations.platform', 
  'locations.platformType', 
  'locations.source', 
  'locations.timestampMS', 
  'locations.velocity', 
  'locations.verticalAccuracy')
display(DF1)
```